# python empty list not adding char at given index

Tags: python

I have this issue where my program makes an empty list and when I use the insert method I have specified a number where I want it to add my char but it puts the char at index zero instead of index 5, for example.

Here is my code:

```
def reverse(text):
    i=len(text)
    txt=""
    ntxt=""
    txt=txt.split()
    for a in text:
        txt.insert(i, a)
        i-=1
    for h in txt:
        ntxt=ntxt+h
    return ntxt
reverse("blaba")
```

Comment: Where is position `4` in an empty list?

Comment: [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) has been there since Python 2.4.

Comment: `list.insert` appends to the end of the list if the index is larger than the size of the list. Personally, I think it should raise an exception. When you try to build the list from the back you are appending to the front.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes I do now know that my question was a really smart one. But I kinda bet that everyone has started with asking a silly question.

Answer (score 2):

Your method of reversing is not what I would call ideal but you need to insert the element at the start of the list each iteration if you want to use insert in an empty list:

```
 for a in text:
    txt.insert(0, a)
```

If you did want to do some inserting following your original logic, you can create a list full of None's and then insert:

```
 txt = [None] * i
 for a in text:
     i -= 1
     txt[i] = a
```

But if you have to were to use indexing, looping over the range length of text -1  in reverse would be a better approach:

```
def reverse(text):
    return "".join([text[i] for i in range(len(text)-1,-1,-1)])
```

In your own code `txt = []` will create an empty list, there is no need to use `txt = ""` then `txt.split()`.

Also if you do just want to reverse a string there is a much simpler way:

```
def reverse(text):
   return text[::-1]
```

Comment: @Richard, no it is a list  txt=txt.split()

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in other answers and comments, there is some errors in your code.

1 Some initialization are useless:

```
txt="" # useless
[...]
txt=txt.split()
```

2 You can't insert at index != 0 in an empty list.
The loop

```
for a in text:
    txt.insert(i, a)
    i-=1
```

will not produce what you are looking for.

3 The second loop

```
for h in txt:
    ntxt=ntxt+h
```

seems to be here to convert an array of chars (txt) into a string (ntxt). There is a built-in function to do that:

```
txt = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ntxt = ''.join(txt)
# ntxt == 'abc'
```

Finally, your function can be simplified to do the same thing

```
def reverse(text):
    result = ''
    for letter in reversed(text):
        result += letter

    return result

print(reverse("abcdef"))
```

The execution of the above code gives

```
fedcba
```

Comment: Well nobody is perfect for the first time otherwise learning would make no sense so I don't really understand the "-3".

But yeah I figured out my problem on my own in the end. I later discovered that I did do it harder and more complicated than I could have, but I think the only right thing is that it works.

Comment: I agree, that's why I edited your question to fix some tiny issues and I answer to help you learning what was wrong in your code. I didn't downvote your question ;)

Comment: ah I see well yes it was a bit broken. I'm also having a hard time grasping what I should try to code. For the moment I'm going through Codecademy but after that I don't really know what to do..